# Function call in jquery each loop on ajax success returns undefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below  the `position` variable in the `$.each` loop of the ajax success method returns undefined when `btn_search` is clicked. 
What I want to achieve is to assign the value of the `checkPosition` function to the variable `position` in the `$.each` loop so I can use the value of the variable to determine what results to display. How can I go about it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url = "{{URL::route('find.paid.trade.cat') }}";
   var position = '';

$(function(){

   $('#btn_search').click(function(e){

    $("#results_tbl").empty();
    var category_id = $('#trade_category').val();
   $.ajax({
      method:'POST',
      url: url,
      data : {
          category_id : category_id,
         },
      success:function(response){

        $.each(response.result, function(index, value){ 

           position = checkPosition(response.result[index]['id']);
          console.log(position);
           if(position == 1){
            $('#results_tbl').append('<tr><td>'+response.result[index]['business_name']+
                    '</td><td><button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" data-cat_id="'+response.result[index]['business_trade_id']+'"'+
                    'data-subscription_id="'+response.result[index]['active_subscription_id']+'" class="btn_make_1st btn-primary btn">1st Positions</button>'+
                    '<button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" class="btn btn_make_2nd btn-info">Make 2nd</button>'+
                    '<button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" class="btn btn_make_3rd btn-success">Make 3rd</button></td>'+
                    '<td></td></tr>')
           }
          else
           {
                $('#results_tbl').append('<tr><td>'+response.result[index]['business_name']+
                    '</td><td><button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" data-cat_id="'+response.result[index]['business_trade_id']+'"'+
                    'data-subscription_id="'+response.result[index]['active_subscription_id']+'" class="btn_make_1st btn-primary btn">Make 1st</button>'+
                    '<button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" class="btn btn_make_2nd btn-info">Make 2nd</button>'+
                    '<button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" class="btn btn_make_3rd btn-success">Make 3rd</button></td>'+
                    '<td></td></tr>')
           }

        })
      },
      error:function(){

      }
   })

});



});



});


 })



function checkPosition(trade_id)
{
    var trade_current_position_url = "{{URL::route('find.position') }}";
    var current_position ;
    $.ajax({
      method:'POST',
      url:trade_current_position_url,
      data:{
        trade_id: trade_id
      },
      success:function(response){
         current_position = response.current_pos;
         returnPosition(current_position);
      },
      error:function(){

      }
    });

}



function returnPosition(position)
{
return position;
}
```

Comment: Can you print your response of ajax call so we can rectify more about issue..

Comment: First, you have the syntax error in your code remove last two method closure '});' from the code. And please specify the problem faced by you!

Comment: @UllasHunka please read my question properly and you will see the issue i am facing.

Comment: please explain the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkPosition function returns undefined always, because does not return anything itself, also answer of its ajax function will be ready after receive result from server. You must pass your works as a function to it:

```
function checkPosition(trade_id, doIfOk){
var trade_current_position_url = "{{URL::route('find.position') }}";
var current_position ;
$.ajax({
  method:'POST',
  url:trade_current_position_url,
  data:{
    trade_id: trade_id
  },
  success:function(response){
     current_position = response.current_pos;
     doIfOk(current_position);
  },
  error:function(){

  }
});
```

Now in your each:

```
checkPosition(response.result[index]['id'], function(position){
      console.log(position);
       if(position == 1){
        $('#results_tbl').append('<tr><td>'+response.result[index]['business_name']+
                '</td><td><button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" data-cat_id="'+response.result[index]['business_trade_id']+'"'+
                'data-subscription_id="'+response.result[index]['active_subscription_id']+'" class="btn_make_1st btn-primary btn">1st Positions</button>'+
                '<button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" class="btn btn_make_2nd btn-info">Make 2nd</button>'+
                '<button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" class="btn btn_make_3rd btn-success">Make 3rd</button></td>'+
                '<td></td></tr>')
       }
      else
       {
            $('#results_tbl').append('<tr><td>'+response.result[index]['business_name']+
                '</td><td><button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" data-cat_id="'+response.result[index]['business_trade_id']+'"'+
                'data-subscription_id="'+response.result[index]['active_subscription_id']+'" class="btn_make_1st btn-primary btn">Make 1st</button>'+
                '<button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" class="btn btn_make_2nd btn-info">Make 2nd</button>'+
                '<button data-id="'+response.result[index]['id']+'" class="btn btn_make_3rd btn-success">Make 3rd</button></td>'+
                '<td></td></tr>')
       }
});
```

Comment: I apologize for the low speed or any mistakes, I typed with my mobile phone.